# $http.get not working at .factory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building a App with Ionic. To start, I create a project based on TABS template.
So, after the creation, i'm trying to get my chats by an API but don't work. That's the code of services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Chats', function($http) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  // var chats = [{
  //   id: 0,
  //   name: 'Ben Sparrow',
  //   lastText: 'You on your way?',
  //   face: 'img/ben.png'
  // }, {
  //   id: 1,
  //   name: 'Max Lynx',
  //   lastText: 'Hey, it\'s me',
  //   face: 'img/max.png'
  // }, {
  //   id: 2,
  //   name: 'Adam Bradleyson',
  //   lastText: 'I should buy a boat',
  //   face: 'img/adam.jpg'
  // }, {
  //   id: 3,
  //   name: 'Perry Governor',
  //   lastText: 'Look at my mukluks!',
  //   face: 'img/perry.png'
  // }, {
  //   id: 4,
  //   name: 'Mike Harrington',
  //   lastText: 'This is wicked good ice cream.',
  //   face: 'img/mike.png'
  // }];
  var chats = function(){ 
    $http.get("http://lucassmuller.com/work/projetoblog/api.php?action=posts")
    .success(function(data) {
        return data;
        console.log='data success';
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log='data error';
    });
  }

  return {
    all: function() {
      return chats;
    },
    remove: function(chat) {
      chats.splice(chats.indexOf(chat), 1);
    },
    get: function(chatId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
          return chats[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

But this aren't working. That can I do to make the $http get the data of API!?

Comment: What happens if you put just it: `return { all: chats, ...`?

Comment: It throws any error?

Comment: Why do you expect the second line to do anything when you have already returned from the function before that?

        return data;
        console.log='data success';

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I just changed it:

```
all: function() {
       return chats;
     },
```

for: `all: chats,`

Also, the methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated, according to this [deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice):

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.

Here's is a snippet working:

```js
 (function() {
   "use strict";
   angular.module('app', [])
     .controller('mainCtrl', function(Chats) {
       Chats.all();
     })

   .factory('Chats', function($http) {
     var chats = function() {
       $http.get("http://lucassmuller.com/work/projetoblog/api.php?action=posts").
       then(function(response) {
         console.log('$http.get worked!!');
       }, function (response) {
         console.log('error!!');
       });
     }
     return {
       all: chats,
       remove: function(chat) {
         chats.splice(chats.indexOf(chat), 1);
       },
       get: function(chatId) {
         for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
           if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
             return chats[i];
           }
         }
         return null;
       }
     };
   });
 })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, so there's another problem and you could make a new question. The original OP asks how to make `$http.get` method works in `factory`.

Comment: `chats` is a function...not array as shown in `remove` and `get`

Comment: @charlietfl probably he has an array that he fills it with the data that comes from `$http.get`, but it's not an issue for this question, anyway.

Comment: The original OP was only to fetch data using `$http.get` in factory.

Comment: Still `Chats.all();` doesn't return anything that OP can use in controller. Logging to console isn't doing anything productive or proving that it works in controller

Comment: The question is: "**$http.get not working at .factory**", what it means? It means that he wants to access `$http.get` in factory, he didn't asks for access it from controller or anything else.

Comment: well they certainly need something returned that they can use. Can clearly see they are replacing hard code array for `$http`

Answer (score 1):

Factory method needs to return the `$http` promise so that you can access data in controller when promise resolves

```
.factory('Chats', function($http) {

      function getChats(){
          // return promise from function
          return $http.get("http://lucassmuller.com/work/projetoblog/api.php?action=posts");
      }

      return {
          all: getChats
      }
}
```

now in controller you use `then()` of promise to assign your data to scope

```
Chats.all().then(function(response){
     $scope.chats = response.data;
});
```

Now if you want to store the array you can use another `then()` in the factory method:

```
.factory('Chats', function($http) {

  var factory = {
    chats: null,
    all: getChats
  };


  return factory;

  function getChats() {
    // return promise from function
    return $http.get("http://lucassmuller.com/work/projetoblog/api.php?action=posts").then(function(response) {
      factory.chats = response.data;
      return factory.chats;
    });
  }

});
```

And in controller

```
Chats.all().then(function(chats){
     $scope.chats = chats;
});
```

Comment: Ok, i did this changes and now its working. Thank you and @developer033 too.

Comment: See revised version that stores array so your other factory methods like `remove` will still work. Just add them to the object `var factory`

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is already answered, please allow me to point out an issue with your code that nobody cared to talk about.

You're using these in your code:

```
//..
console.log='data success';
// some code     
console.log='data error';
```

The correct way to use `console.log` is to pass a parameter to it since its a function. Rougly, your browser has code like this:

```
function console() {
  this.log = function() {
    // code that logs to the console
  }
}
```

When you do `console.log = 'data success'`, you are assigning the string `'data success'` to the `log` property of console `object`. There reference to the actual functional code is lost and `console.log` will not work the way it should for rest of the page.

```
console.log('I work fine');
console.log = 'I screw things up!';
console.log('I cannot log to the console'); // every `console.log`s below here do not work
```