# Error showing data in AngularJS for Ionic App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm doing a app for Ionic. Based on answers in a question made by me at [$http.get not working at .factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214250/http-get-not-working-at-factory), I wrote the following code:

**services.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Chats', function($http) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  var factory = {
    chats: null,
    all: function() { return chats; },
    get: function(chatId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
          return chats[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };

  $http.get("http://lucassmuller.com/work/projetoblog/api.php?action=posts").then(function(data) {
    factory.chats = data;
    console.log('data ok');
  });

  return factory;

});
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

But when I run it to do a ng-repeat with data, shows an error saying that chats is not defined. How can I fix it?

Comment: you might need to inject the `starter.services` into `starter.controllers` as a dependency module.

Comment: Try `angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services
'])` in the controller.js file

Comment: But in app.js they are connected: `angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])`

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted @LucasMüller

Comment: Sure. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request that you make to any HTTP resource won't be resolved right away. It returns a `promise` object which is literally a promise saying that *Hey, I don't know the result right now, but I will give you a result later regardless it succeeds or not*. The promise object is *resolved* in the controller using its `.then` property which takes two functions as parameters, `onSuccess` and `onFailure`.

In your case, this is how you do it.

**Factory/Service**

```
.factory('Chats', function($http) {

  // returning a promise from the service
  var chats = $http.get("http://lucassmuller.com/work/projetoblog/api.php?action=posts");

  var factory = {
    chats: null,
    all: function() { return chats; },
    get: function(chatId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
          return chats[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };

  return factory;

});
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  // resolving the promise in the controller
  Chats.all().then(function (res){ // onSuccess, called when response is successfully recieved
    var chats = res.data
    console.log(chats);
    $scope.chats = chats;
  }, function (err){ // onFailure, called when error response
       console.log(err);
  });
})
```

Check Angular Documentation for [`$http` promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).